# How to make outgoing call with token

Tags: cocoapods, twilio

I am using Twilio in my project which is in swift 4. for Voice call. In My Project I have used Twilio CocoaPods.

I have implemented getting accesstoken from API and implemented make call functionality as per document, but I am not able connect the call since I'm getting `timeout error`.

Comment: Hi, please share some code

Comment: Hey, would love to help, but need a bit more information here. Can you share some code and some more details about when you get the timeout?

Comment: Hi ,i am using this code for make call if (self.call != nil && self.call?.state == .connected) {
                performEndCallAction(uuid: self.call!.uuid)

            } else {
                let uuid = UUID()
                let handle = "Voice"
                performStartCallAction(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
            }